# Create a system of linear equations with $n$ variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have written some function that does matrix computation. I have tested them on $2\times 2,\, 3\times 3,\, 4\times4$ matrices derived from system of linear equations.

Now, I am having difficulty in finding system of equations in $5,6,7$ etc variables.

Is there a general way by which I can obtain such linear systems which are consistent?

Comment: Yes, the method of row reduction, which is computationally efficient: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Row_Reduction_and_Echelon_Forms

Comment: @mvw No *multiplication* its computation (rank, qr, etc). Yes, I need to form consistent system of linear equation in $n$ dimensions, for  $n \geqslant 5$.

Comment: @Travis Do you mean I should proceed backwards from *reduced row echelon* ?

Comment: Take any upper triangular matrix with no zeros on the diagonal. Take any lower triangular matrix with no zeros on the diagonal. Multiply them, and you'll get a matrix for which all linear systems are consistent.

Comment: Oh, I see, the question is about how to *produce* systems which are consistent. Of course $A {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ is consistent for all matrices $A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you add that as an answer with a bit of explanation.

Comment: @Travis I'd surely like to formulate a system of equations with *non-trivial* solution.

Comment: @vvy In that case one can simply choose (square) $A$ with zero determinant. If you want to produce examples $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}$ with nonzero $\bf b$, you can use the method you suggested earlier, namely starting with a (augmented) matrix $\pmatrix{A&|&{\bf b}}$ in RREF and corresponding to a soluble system and apply arbitrary row operations, or equivalently, multiply the augmented matrix on the left by an arbitrary invertible matrix. This method is totally general in the sense that every consistent (finite) linear system arises this way, for the simple reason that every matrix has a RREF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form of a system of linear equations is
$$
A x = b
$$
where $A \in F^{m \times n}$, $x \in F^n$ and $b \in F^m$ and $F$ is some field.

It is consistent, if there exist solutions $x$.

The simplest case, as Travis noted in the comments, are homogeneous systems
$$
A x = 0
$$
because they always have the solution $x = 0$, independent of the choice of $A$.

A nice special case are the systems with $m = n$, thus having the same number of unknowns and (row) equations, which have one solution $x = A^{-1} b$.

You might start with the identity matrix $I_n$ of dimension $n$: 
\begin{align}
& I_n x = b \iff \\
& (I_n \mid b) \iff \\
& (I_n^{(0)} \mid b^{(0)})
\end{align}
and then apply a couple of elementary row transformations:
$$
(I_n^{(k+1)} \mid b^{(k+1)}) = (E_{k+1} I_n^{(k)} \mid E_{k+1} b^{(k)})
$$
where $E_{k}$ does multiply a row by a non-zero scalar multiple or
adds a scalar multiple of another row to a given row.
Such operations do not change the solution set and after a couple of them you should end up with a nice matrix and solution vector, which have not too many zero entries.

This is basically an inverted Gauss elimination procedure.

If $m > n$ one would start with
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r|r}
I_n & b \\
0_{(m-n) \times n} & 0_{m-n}
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
and apply elementary row operations $E_k$.

Example:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & b_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & b_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & b_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If $m < n$ then this has the consequence that $n-m$ variables stay free and can attain arbitrary values.

E.g. if the first $m$ variables are not free then we start with
$$
(I_m 0_{m \times (n-m)} \mid b) 
$$

If we want to bind / free other unknowns $x_i$ then we need to redistribute the $m$ non-zero $1$ entries.

Example:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & b_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Here we have $x_2, x_3$ and $x_6$ as free variables.

Comment: Thank you for such lucid explanation! Can you please add some information about the other two cases i.e. $n>m$ and $n<m$

Answer (score 2):

Take a random matrix $A$ and a random vector $x$. Let be $b = Ax$.
The system $Ax = b$ ($x$ unknown vector this time) surely will be consistent.